# Xamarin Forms: How to set FontAttributes Bold for a custom font

Tags: fonts, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project use FontAwesome follow this link:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31530/fontawesome-label-heres-how

It work well. But when I add this code:

```
myLabel.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
```

The icon becomes an rectangle image with "?" in it.

I think it's because the custom font I set is just in normal font attribute. How can I set font for bold attribute in Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so FontAwesome does not support bold type. So I have to use the normal font attribute.